# custom leading space in the web interface

Tags: css

If I already custom `ul` and `li` tags in my web interface, then I still want to custom leading space each line.

Is there any possible way to create a custom leading space?

For example, if I cannot predict when and where the line will be changed in each sentence. And I still want to show the interface looks like that

<1> In this lesson, you'll learn what a clause is and how to use different types of clauses to make 
         your writing more interesting

<2> If the clause could stand by itself, and form a complete sentence with punctuation, we call the 
          clause an independent clause. The following are independent clauses

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you post your HTML / CSS code and your attempt so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use a css `counter` and absolutely position it in the `content` using the puesdo selector `:before` on the `<li />`. Just make sure you give your `<li />`'s enough `padding-left`.

[See the Fiddle for a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r0ose5vm/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>In this lesson, you'll learn what a clause is and how to use different types of clauses to make your writing more interesting</li>
<li>If the clause could stand by itself, and form a complete sentence with punctuation, we call the clause an independent clause. The following are independent clauses</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
  width:300px; /*Just for demo*/
  list-style:none;
  counter-reset: section; 
}

li{
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  padding-left:32px;
}
li:before{
  counter-increment: section;
  content:"<" counter(section) ">";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```